# Installing curl inside nginx docker image

Tags: curl, nginx, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile few lines suppose to install curl inside the nginx custom image to run under ubuntu.
The second group of code is an attempt to convert the task to do the same but to run on Amazon Linux.

Any suggestion as to what would be the yum equivalent to the rest of the apt-get command?
`-no-install-recommends curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

```
//Dockerfile for ubuntu
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -no-install-recommends curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

```js
//Dockerfile for Amazon linux
FROM nginx
RUN yum update && yum install -y curl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're asking how to get the Amazon Linux-based Dockerfile to install curl without prompting you, you can add -y to yum update:

```
//Dockerfile for Amazon linux
FROM nginx
RUN yum -y update && yum install -y curl
```

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking. The question is in regards to the rest of the apt-get command which installed recommended dependencies. Also you put the `-y` after yum then after install in the second command.

Comment: no, there is no analog to 'recommended' dependencies when using yum like there is with apt-get. have you tried running the second Dockerfile build?

Answer (score 10):

For Nginx image use Debian as OS use below : -

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 2):

`-no-install-recommends curl`

should be

`--no-install-recommends curl`

you forgot to put double-dash

Comment: Be wary that `--no-install-recommends` may leave your image without certs needed to trust common services like GitHub.